# Eclipse closing down suddenly without any warning

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I  am using downloaded  Eclipse Juno from official website  for android programming . What is happening that my  Eclipse close down suddenly without saving my code  and that problem is really killing me . I search on Google the i find a bug with Ubuntu in this [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/08w667yi5bylqp2/hs_err_pid3953.log?dl=0)
. As in this link problem is with Open JDK so i uninstall Open JDK 6 and install Oracle JDK 7 . set path in profile directory . But still i am getting same problem . **The** error log file is as given
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/08w667yi5bylqp2/hs_err_pid3953.log?dl=0)

Please get me rid of this problem . I already spend lot of time in it. Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: It could be something to check with Android SDK as well. Reason being, i am using Eclipse JUNO and JDK 1.7 and it works fine on my Ubuntu Laptop, but i do not develop any android applications. I had the same issue while using Kepler and not since when i started using Juno.

Comment: So how resolve this issue with Kepler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yesterday i have same problem and i solved this issue by adding few line in eclipse.ini file

```
-XX:-UseCompressedOops
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```